# how to use setTimeout more than once simultaneously in nodejs

Tags: node.js, httprequest, settimeout

I have created a http server in node.js and I want a function to run after specific time every time when there is a request. I tried using setTimeout() for this. But the problem is I want multiple timers to be running simultaneously and setTimeout resets each time a new request is made. Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Here is the code which i tried:

```
http.createServer(getVersion).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);

function getVersion(req, res) {
    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname === "/") {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        Downloadurls.find({ Downloadurl : randstring }).exec(function (err,result) {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            if (!result.length) { 
                Downloadurl_doc = new Downloadurls({
                Downloadurl: randstring
                });
                Downloadurl_doc.save();
            }
        });
    }, timeoutSeconds*1000);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Time left: '+getTimeLeft(timeout)+'s');
    if (getTimeLeft(timeout) === 0)
       { clearInterval(interval);}
    }, 1000);

    function getTimeLeft(randstring1[i]) {
        return Math.ceil((timeout._idleStart + timeout._idleTimeout - Date.now()) / 1000);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  `setTimeout()` doesn't reset anything when it's called more than once.  It creates a new timer event for each time it's called.  Perhaps you have a problem because you're reusing the same `timeout` variable over and over.

Comment: yeah that was the mistake I did. declared the timeout as a global variable. thanks for enlightening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* this is happening because `timeout` and `interval` are declared in the global scope, then they're overridden at each request (they refer to same variable). Instead, try to use `var` to force those variable to `getVersion`'s function scope:

```
....
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
....
var interval = setInterval(function() {
....
```

*I wrote "maybe" because I didn't test it, but makes sense. Anyway, avoid global scope variables if don't needed*